# warning icon on fields

Tags: fieldtypes

I am seeing warning icons on drop down fields like this
[image: Drop down with warnings]

Where does this come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning appears when the content column type of the current selected field is different than the new one -> you'll lose all the information that is currently stored.

For example: changing from number to text won't be a huge problem but changing from text to date will result in a data loss

Comment: DO you mean its just information or that there is something wrong? In the middle of a build I don't want to be frightened that the database is going to be 'corrupted' . Its not clear from the UX of this if any action is required

Comment: It's just an information. When you change the type you'll lose data